# Match pattern from array php

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching, match

I have an array, such as this example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cinema
    [1] => school
    [2] => college
    [3] => social
    [4] => cinema
    [5] => School
    [6] => COllEGE
    [7] => Ccccccc
)
```

I want only whole words that start from 'C' or 'S' only one time, 
repetition character in word is allowed irrespective of whether they are upper or lower case

Example output:

```
cinema
college
ccccccc
```

Comment: Why did you pick `college` and not `school` for the output?

Comment: Your sample output does not seem to match your specification. 'cinema' and 'college' appear multiple times.

Comment: @nickb 'cause college contain more uppercase letter. ok forget both upper case and lowercase try a pattern match without it.

Comment: @NathanielFord here no-repetition means in the output. One pattern one time in output. and cinema and college both starts from 'C'

Comment: *"I want only whole words that start from 'C' or 'S' only one time (no repetition)"* - Then why does `Ccccccc` match?

Comment: @MikeB
means output must like to be
`cinema
 cinema <- Repeated
 college`
ccccccc

Comment: @BasicBridge Your desired output is clear. Your rules are horribly worded.

Comment: @MikeB tried my best as being from non english country

Comment: Using the term/tag Regular Expressions and the phrase *"'I want only whole words that start from 'C' or 'S' only one time"* implies that a word can start with the letters C or S only once. And since `Cccccc` starts with many C's it would violate your rule. You probably mean to say that the result-set will only contain unique values regardless of casing.

Comment: @MikeB thanks so much for understanding me. yes mean this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php) with a simple filter (regex or `$val[0] == "c"` for instance) and [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php)

Here is an example (not tested) :

```
$data = array(...data...);

function check_value($val) {
  return preg_match('/^c/i', $val);
}

$output = array_unique(array_filter($data, 'check_value'));
```

Comment: This won't entirely solve it, though it makes massaging the array easier. Specifically, array_filter would leave duplicates in the result array.

Comment: You should try putting up some sample code: I think you'll find there are a few implementation details to work out, but you're on the right track.

Comment: array_filter is case sensitive

Comment: array_filter can't be case sensitive, your filter can. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

The php manuals [list of array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) and [list of string functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php) may be of use:

```
<?php
  $arr =  array ( 'cinema', 'school', 'college', 'social', 'cinema', 'School', 'COllEGE' );
  $massaged_array = massage($arr);
  $result = array_count_values($massaged_array);
  foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    if (substr_compare($key, 'C', 0, 1) || substr_compare($key, 'S', 0, 1)){
      echo $key;
    }
  }    

  function massage ($arr) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
      $result[] = strtolower($value);
    }
    return $result;
  }
```

Comment: getting Warning: array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null

Comment: That's because I forgot to return `$result` from `massage()`. Updated; sorry, I'm not actually testing this out.